# Why does the intensity of an uncollided beam of neutrons post-target drop off exponentially with the thickness of the target?

Tags: nuclear-physics, collision

I guess I would have thought it was linear. The exponential dropoff surprised me and I don't understand why it's the case--can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is simple.

we divide the target thickness into discrete slabs of equal thickness. Imagine that after traversing the first slab element, 50% of the neutrons have been absorbed. Then, after the second slab, we have 50% of 50% or 25% of the original beam strength remaining. After three slabs we have 50% of 25% or 12.5%; four slabs is 50% of 12.5 or 6.25%, five slabs is 3.125% and so on.

If you plot these percentages as a function of the number of slabs traversed, you get a decaying exponential.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a monoenergetic beam of neutrons all traveling in the x direction through a slab target.  Let $I_0$ be the intensity (neutrons per square cm per sec) incident on the slab, denoted as the flux.  Let $\Sigma$ represent the macroscopic cross section of the target (units are 1/cm).  See any physics/nuclear engineering test for a discussion of the macroscopic cross section, such as Lamarsh, Introduction to Nuclear Reactor Theory.  $\Sigma$ dx is the probability of an interaction within the differential length dx; therefore, $\Sigma$ is the probability of an interaction per unit path length. The change in intensity as a function of the distance in the absorber is $dI(x)/dx = - \Sigma \enspace I(x) \enspace dx$ , which yields $I(x) = I_0 \enspace e^{-\Sigma x}$ for the *uncollided* flux at a distance x into the slab.

Note: some of the neutrons that scattered (as opposed to being absorbed) are still present but they are not counted as part of the *uncollided* beam.  To evaluate the total distribution of neutrons at a given point in a medium is not so simple as to evaluate the uncollided neutrons; transport theory (or if applicable diffusion theory) is required. Also the energy distribution of the neutrons must be considered.